# Infinite Scrolling andersonferminiano.com

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll

I am using this script http://andersonferminiano.com/jqueryscrollpagination/
But i have an issue, the script doesnt work in Chrome only in IE

Can anybody help me with this or suggest me another infinity scrolling script?
I will use it with php and mysql.

Thanks in advance!
George